# How to define date objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have my dates stored as a string values in variables sDate and eDate. I have to compare them in java script. Before I compare the dates I have to define them as Date objects. I tried to use this:

```
var jsObj = {};
<cfoutput query="getQuery">
jsObj["#year#_#Id#"].startdate = "#DateFormat(sDate,'mm/dd/yyyy')#";
jsObj["#year#_#Id#"].enddate = "#DateFormat(eDate,'mm/dd/yyyy')#";
</cfoutput>

var sDate = new Date('mm/dd/yyyy');
var eDate = new Date('mm/dd/yyyy');

if(aartemp[1] == bldg){
    if(jsObj[key].startdate == sDate || jsObj[key].enddate == eDate){
        alert('Error!');
    }
}
```

I got an error when I tried to print value sDate that says is not defined. If you know what I should change please let me know.

Comment: `new Date('mm/dd/yyyy');` - what do you think that does?

Comment: What are those `#` in the string literals? What serverside templating engine are you using, and how does the output JS look like?

Comment: Use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) for date handling

Comment: I use # form values from ColdFusion.

Comment: What does #DateFormat()# output into your template?  Is it a date value in 'mm/dd/yyyy' format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace the characters by digits, representing a real date in `new Date('mm/dd/yyyy')`, e.g. `new Date('05/05/2015')`.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the Date() constructor, you need to pass it a value to make into the date - not a template for formatting the date.  You can either make a Date object by calling Date(), which gives you the current date/time, or you need to supply some value(s) to create the date.  Here are some examples from [MDN page for the Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

```
var today = new Date();
var birthday = new Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00');
var birthday = new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00');
var birthday = new Date(1995, 11, 17);
var birthday = new Date(1995, 11, 17, 3, 24, 0);
```

if "#DateFormat(sDate,'mm/dd/yyyy')#" outputs a date in 'mm/dd/yyyy' format, you could use that to initialize your dates:

```
<cfoutput query="getQuery">
jsObj["#year#_#Id#"].startdate = "#DateFormat(sDate,'mm/dd/yyyy')#";
jsObj["#year#_#Id#"].enddate = "#DateFormat(eDate,'mm/dd/yyyy')#";
</cfoutput>

var sDate = new Date(jsObj["#year#_#Id#"].startdate);
var eDate = new Date(jsObj["#year#_#Id#"].enddate);
```